# What is a naming standard for multi-word struct type in Go?

Tags: go, struct

I am reading mixed opinions on how to name structs and the files that contain them. I'm also having a hard time finding detail on multi-word structs.

What is the most standard way to name my structs and the files that contain them in the following project?

I have an executable project with 2 structs:

- `Foo`
- `FooBar`

I want to declare the structs in their own file so I can create test files. Each will get imported into `main.go`.

- Do I name the structs `PascalCase`? if not, how?
- How should the go files be named?

edit:

This doc is why I went with Pascal Case first, but it is a one word struct and doesn't show it being used in a separate file. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/2

Comment: [Effective Go: MixedCaps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps)

Comment: @icza so it's best practice in my case to have files named: `FooBar.go` and `FooBar_test.go`?

Comment: No, this is just the Go identifier naming convention. You could name your files like `foobar.go` and `foobar_test.go`.

Comment: What to name your structs and what to name your files are two totally different questions.

Comment: @Adrian you obviously did not read the post. Should at least do that before you downvote.

Comment: "I want to declare the structs in their own file so I can create test files." You can create test no matter how you name your structs or in how many files you decalre them or how you name these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effective go blog post in the official Golang blog helps a lot with this.
The [Package Names](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names) section and the [Mixed Caps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps) as suggested by icza are specially helpful.

I also had this discussion with the community in the official slack channel a couple months ago, and most agreed that files should be always lowercase. If the names are too big, you can use underscores , be be careful: the go build will ignore files starting with `_`, and don't use specific suffixes, like `_test.go` and OS/arch names, like `_amd64.go`  or `_linux.go`. The build tool will only use those last ones in the specific OSs/architectures. This is specified the the [build docs](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).

So if you are creating a struct called `FooBar`, your file can either be `foobar.go` or `foo_bar.go`.